# Dialog Fragment(custom layout) is not working when displaying TextView

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have read some of the posts here but they dont seem to fix my problem.

[image]

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog my_alert=new dialog();
            my_alert.show(getFragmentManager(),"");
        }
    });

}
}
```

**dialog.java**

```
public class dialog extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder build=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    View v;
    inflater=getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout,null); 
    build.setView(v);
    return build.create();

}
```

}

The above coding is working before I add textview.

However, what I want to do is to display textview in the custom layout. If I add the following coding below `build.setView(v)` , it exits.

```
build.setView(v)
TextView tv=(TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView);
tv.setText("my text here");
return build.create();
```

Logcat error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this); Don't  extend from DialogFragment and user the builder into your activity. You can use builder.setView() to use a custom view

Comment: if dont extend, that means i have to put inside mainactivity? I want to separate the java class.  and for your solution, can you explain more?

Comment: Check whether your dialog_layout.xml has TextView with ID "textView"

Comment: In this case, create a class which extends from a Dialog. In your activity just create your dialog with : new  MyCustomDialog() .. and in order to show the dialog use myCustomDialog.show()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this  in **onCreateDialog()**

```
View v;
inflater=getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout,null); 
TextView tv=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
tv.setText("my text here");**
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

tv is null.Maybe you should define  a TextView label in layout dialog_layout.

```
TextView tv=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
tv.setText("my text here");
```

and use this code find it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is here:

```
TextView tv=(TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

replace 
     getActivity() 
with 
    v (the layout that you're inflating)

try this,

```
TextView tv=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Answer (score 0):

your dialog view is dialog_layout, which mean there is a textview in dialog_layout. Am i right? Then how come below you are not getting the textview from dialog_layout view?

```
build.setView(v)
TextView tv=(TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView);  //--> which view is the textview from?
tv.setText("my text here");
return build.create();
```

Comment: yes i am getting from there. the problem is   change from getActivity() to v. then solved!